# Symfony2.5 voters cannot use the denyAccessUnlessGranted method

Tags: php, symfony

I implement security with the voters on a Symfony 2.5 application. Except that, I note that the denyAccessUnlessGranted method can be used from version 2.6. Someone there a workaround ? thanks

Comment: This method is simply a shortcut for `isGranted()`. Take a look at the definition of the method and implement it in your application. [Controller.php](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Controller/Controller.php#L149)

Comment: If possible, I'd recommend upgrading to 2.7 with long term support. 2.5 nor 2.6 [are not supported anymore](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#schedule).

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've upgrade to 2.7